# Partitioning DB tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-cluster

What is the best strategy to make a clustered MySQL deployment in which some tables of the DB are placed on one node and some other tables are placed on another node while acting as a single coherent DB from the application's perspective?

Let's say if I have 2 data nodes A and B, and a database with 5 tables, I want tables 1, 2, and 3 to be placed on node A and tables 4 and 5 to be placed on node B.

Do we need this deployment to be a clustered deployment, or would a typical MySQL deployment handle this? If yes, how so?

How about having table 4 replicated on both A and B?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. The tag [tag:cluster-analysis] was inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will allow for transparent access to tables stored on other instances using the federated engine (this has been available for a long time).

MySQL does provide a feature called partitioning - which is applied to tables to distribute the data across different filesystems - but this is something very different.

> How about having table 4 replicated on both A and B?

You can set up mysql replication to only copy specific tables (see replicate-wild-do-table) however mixing federation and replication is going to get very confusing very quickly - get it wrong and you will trash your data. Use one or the other. Not both.